# Adding a blank page to SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I'm creating a report by account that will either print 2 pages duplex (front and back). But sometimes the amount of data will make it overflow to 3 pages. When that happens I need to make sure a 4th page gets generated (blank) so the next account can print on the front of page 1. How can I accomplish this in VS2010? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, like most formatting questions, is to use a **Rectangle**.

Insert a rectangle, place it after your first table and give it a height of 0.125in. In the Rectangle properties, check **Add Page Break After**.

Now the problem is with your needing to only use the rectangle's page break when it's on page 2.

Since the Page Number built-in field only works in the header or footer, you need some code for the page number. Add code to get the Page Number to the report **code** (Report Properties -> Code):

```
Public Function PageNumber() as integer
     Return Me.Report.Globals!PageNumber
End Function
```

Then set the Rectangle's **visibility** to **Show or Hide based on expression** and the expression to:

```
=IIF(Code.PageNumber() = 3, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Comment: I already have a rectangle that encompasses the entire report and has 2 tables on it But I do now have a field brought in from the sp to know how many pages are needed for the account (2, 3 or 4). Should I incorporate another rectangle then and setup the visibility using that field like your saying instead of the page number?

Comment: If you already have a field in your data, then you might as well use it. And yes - you would need a new rectangle for it.