# SSRS / PBI Report Builder - How can I force a subreport to always start on an odd page number?

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, powerbi-paginated-reports

I am making a paginated report which has 4 subreports in them.
It is a report which prints various student information for a whole class at once.
So if a class has 20 students it will print the same report 20 times, once for each student (of course the data varies per student).

Now I've run into an issue; teacher like to print this report double sided, but if the report for student #1 ends on an odd page number, the first page from the report for student #2 starts on even page number. This means that this report will start on the back side of the page if you print it out double-sided.
This is unwanted since these reports need to be separated for each student.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem? I thought about somehow forcing the first sub report to start on an odd page number, or to add a blank page if the last subreport ends on an odd page number, but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

I thought about somehow forcing the first sub report to start on an odd page number, or to add a blank page if the last subreport ends on an odd page number, but I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a blank page to SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344809/adding-a-blank-page-to-ssrs)

Comment: Hi David, 
Thanks for your reply. I've tried the solution described in the answer but it doesn't seem to do anything in my report.

Comment: Maybe this is cause Im using sub reports? I dont think thats the case for the question you linked.